# Google и Яндекс заблокировали сайт

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

У меня беда. Сидел неделю разрабатывал сайт. И вот настал долгожданный день когда я открываю его.

Снял с robots.txt блокировку на индексацию.  Потом зашел в гугл и яндекс для вебмастеров, добавил туда свой сайт ииииии......получил бан на сайт. Фатальную ошибку. Агрессивный спам. Кто знает о чем речь, понимает что это мягко говоря трындец для сайта.

Я не знаю за что он так со мной, наверное у меня действительно плохая карма. Может всё не так плохо и я зря себя накручиваю, пожалуйста кто понимает в чём может быть проблема, подскажите.

Я и домен купил и сертификат, время и сил потратил не ради того что бы меня в первые же пол часа заблокировали. Как поступить в такой ситуации.

Вот обсуждаемый сайт: https://csfile.ru

Добавлю, впервые что то довёл до конца и это прям наказание какое то.
Текст для сайта писал из головы, не копировал.

Comment: А как выглядит бан? Гугл и яндекс сайт еще не проиндексировали и он не выдается даже через sit: domain

Comment: [Ссылка на Яндекс](https://csfile.ru/template/images/yandex.png)
[Ссылка на Google](https://csfile.ru/template/images/google.png)

Comment: А что яндекс называет основными принципами читали?

Comment: Я так понимаю, репутация домена была просто испорчена предыдущими его владельцами. Думаю, есть смысл пытаться обращаться в какие-нибудь техподдержки, так как сейчас я на сайте ничего особо криминального не вижу (ну, кроме того, что сайт сам по себе пиратит игры, но вряд ли причиной является именно это)

Comment: Основные принципы читал, там про оригинальность и тд. Да мой сайт не единственный в своём жанре. Но ему есть место быть. Это же обычная конкуренция. Я не знаю как написать в тех поддержку. Тут есть функции только сообщить об исправлении ошибки. Но тут ждать месяц. Я как бы сообщил. Но я ничего и не исправлял, т.к. понятия не имею что я должен исправить) обида...

Comment: А вы полюбуйтесь, что на этом сайте было год назад: http://web.archive.org/web/20170529113241/http://csfile.ru/

Comment: Хехе) Ну радует что это не я косяк. теперь нужно ждать месяц? или быть можно ускорить процесс перепросмотра сайта?

Comment: Попробуйте начать с доступности вашего веб-сайта. Вызов вашего веб-сайта возвращает следующее: "Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!
Пожалуйста сообщите об ошибке администратору: admin@csfile.ru".

Comment: Проблему решил, написал в Тех.Поддержку яндекса и google. Сказал что я новый владелец домена. Все санкции сняли, теперь сайт в поисковике.